# Github Actions Jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jestjs, github-actions

My Jest tests are passing, but Github actions workflow isn't completing.

Here's my main.yaml.

```
name: Jest Unit Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x]
        mongodb-version: ['4.2', '4.4', '5.0']
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Start MongoDB
        uses: supercharge/mongodb-github-action@1.7.0
        with:
          mongodb-version: ${{ matrix.mongodb-version }}
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run workflow
    env: 
      CI: true
```

[image]

Do I need to fix my yaml file?

Comment: This usually means the process isn't exiting or some background process isn't exiting.  so while it runs all tests and outputs results the underlying node process didn't exit.  sometimes you don't notice in an interactive shell.  It's hard to tell without looking at the tests themselves.

Comment: you can look at the tests here: https://github.com/DAT-Cash/datweave/tree/main/tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out Github issues has issues with async processes. Even though the tests passed, there were still async operations occurring from Jest, so Github actions defaults to not completing.

Fix this by adding `--forceExit` to force the test to end and `--detectOpenHandles` to see what async operations are still happening.

Added these to my `package.json` scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "local-test": "jest --watchAll",
    "workflow": "jest --forceExit --detectOpenHandles",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```

For those new to Github actions, the yaml file in my original post calls `npm run workflow` at the end, which is the script in my `package.json`.

See https://jestjs.io/docs/cli for more info on the Jest options.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the type of issue I was referring to.  Note that when you say Github actions defaults to not completing, it's actually node.  In github actions, we just run the command line you specify and wait for it to exit with a return code.

Answer (score 0):

Please also ensure your jest has no warnings during pipeline running:

eg: `Jest: "global" coverage threshold for branches (10%) not met: 8.33%`

Such as ensure the threshold value is always passed:

you can setup something like below in `jest.config.js` file:

```
coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 1,
      functions: 1,
      lines: 1,
      statements: 1,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "--watchAll" from the command, and add other for GitHub Workflow

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "jest --watchAll",
   "ghworkflowtest": "jest"
}
```

Run "npm test" for local tests and in .yml file call "npm run ghworkflowtest" for GitHub actions